# Refreshing the cache with CacheEventListener on notifyExpired

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

My projet need to keep some data from a an SQL DB in a cache for business service needs.  Theses data are like system parameter that can be changed by an admin app.

The spec tell me that some of those data need to be refreshed every 2 min.

I have used Spring 3 + Hibernate 3.6 + ehcache to do this.

For the 2 min refresh requirement, i have configured my ehcache.xml like this:

```
<cache name="xxx.yyy.zzz.domain.Parameter"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120" statistics="true">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory class="xxx.yyy.zzz.listner.CacheListnerFactory" properties="bean=myCacheEventListner" listenFor="all"/>

    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />

</cache>
```

my listener notify method get called when this cache exipre.. nice.  But from the Doc. of ehcache, i read that the remove block until the notify method returns!!!!  i wanted to use this notify method to call back the DB and reload the data in the cache!.

How can i implement this behavior with cacheEventListener.

here is my listener code:

```
    @Override
public void notifyElementExpired(Ehcache arg0, Element arg1) {
    log.info("CACHE EXPIRED : " + arg0.getName());
    log.info("CACHE EXPIRED ELEMENT: " + arg1);
    log.info("RELOADING CACHE");
    List<Parameter> params = servParam.getAllParameter();
    for (Parameter p : params) {
        servParam.getParameter(p.getCodeParam(), p.getCodeMarche());
    }


}
```

and this is a part of the logs from my junit:

```
<ENTER testGetParameterExpired>
<enter - get parameters - code param = PAIEMENT_FACTURE_DELAI_MIN code marche = P>
<CACHE EXPIRED : [ name = auport.commun.shared.domain.Parameter status = STATUS_ALIVE eternal = false overflowToDisk = true maxEntriesLocalHeap = 1000 maxEntriesLocalDisk = 0 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = LRU timeToLiveSeconds = 5 timeToIdleSeconds = 0 persistence = LOCALTEMPSWAP diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds = 120 cacheEventListeners: auport.commun.shared.listner.MyCacheEventListner net.sf.ehcache.statistics.LiveCacheStatisticsWrapper  hitCount = 2 memoryStoreHitCount = 2 diskStoreHitCount = 0 missCountNotFound = 5 missCountExpired = 1 maxBytesLocalHeap = 0 overflowToOffHeap = false maxBytesLocalOffHeap = 0 maxBytesLocalDisk = 0 pinned = false ]>
<CACHE EXPIRED ELEMENT: [ key = sql: select parameter0_.cod_paap as cod1_0_, parameter0_.cod_mrch as cod2_0_, parameter0_.TMS_MAJ as TMS3_0_, parameter0_.NOM_ANGL_PAAP as NOM4_0_, parameter0_.nom_fran_paap as nom5_0_, parameter0_.NOM_UTLR_MAJ as NOM6_0_, parameter0_.NUM_UTLR_MAJ as NUM7_0_, parameter0_.PRN_UTLR_MAJ as PRN8_0_, parameter0_.VAL_PAAP as VAL9_0_ from TABCOMMUN.TPAAP parameter0_ where parameter0_.cod_paap=? and parameter0_.cod_mrch=?; parameters: PAIEMENT_FACTURE_DELAI_MIN, P, ; named parameters: {}, value=[5519186315907073, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1f6d2e3], version=1, hitCount=1, CreationTime = 1347457596657, LastAccessTime = 1347457596750 ]>
<RELOADING CACHE>
<enter - get all parameters>
<CACHE EXPIRED : [ name = auport.commun.shared.domain.Parameter status = STATUS_ALIVE eternal = false overflowToDisk = true maxEntriesLocalHeap = 1000 maxEntriesLocalDisk = 0 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = LRU timeToLiveSeconds = 5 timeToIdleSeconds = 0 persistence = LOCALTEMPSWAP diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds = 120 cacheEventListeners: auport.commun.shared.listner.MyCacheEventListner net.sf.ehcache.statistics.LiveCacheStatisticsWrapper  hitCount = 2 memoryStoreHitCount = 2 diskStoreHitCount = 0 missCountNotFound = 6 missCountExpired = 2 maxBytesLocalHeap = 0 overflowToOffHeap = false maxBytesLocalOffHeap = 0 maxBytesLocalDisk = 0 pinned = false ]>
<CACHE EXPIRED ELEMENT: [ key = sql: select parameter0_.cod_paap as cod1_0_, parameter0_.cod_mrch as cod2_0_, parameter0_.TMS_MAJ as TMS3_0_, parameter0_.NOM_ANGL_PAAP as NOM4_0_, parameter0_.nom_fran_paap as nom5_0_, parameter0_.NOM_UTLR_MAJ as NOM6_0_, parameter0_.NUM_UTLR_MAJ as NUM7_0_, parameter0_.PRN_UTLR_MAJ as PRN8_0_, parameter0_.VAL_PAAP as VAL9_0_ from TABCOMMUN.TPAAP parameter0_; parameters: ; named parameters: {}, value=[5519186315202560, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1286b10, [Ljava.lang.Object;@8d2280, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1d4340c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@a51027, [Ljava.lang.Object;@c7833c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@790192, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5646a5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@381a9c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@15b011c], version=1, hitCount=0, CreationTime = 1347457596485, LastAccessTime = 1347457596485 ]>
<RELOADING CACHE>
<enter - get all parameters>
...
```

As you can see, the call to getParemeters trigger the expired event, then the getAllParameter is called to refresh the cache but this call re-trigger the expired event... so the process to refresh the cache is done twice!!!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the code to reload data into cache into another method (in another bean) and use the spring @Async annotation to execute it asynchronously.

This way the callback will return and ehcache would remove the entry from the cache (hopefully before the async call gets triggered).

There is still a chance that the async might happen before the entry is removed in which case you might get duplicate calls to the listener - but that will be rare.